# Write multiple values to binary file

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <Magick++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Magick;
using namespace std;

unsigned short int version = 1;
unsigned short int cols, rows;
short int myCol, myRow;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  ofstream myFile;
  myFile.open("img001.bin", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);
  myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*> (&version), sizeof(version));

  try {
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Image img("noname-th.jpg");
    cols = img.columns();
    rows = img.rows();
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&cols), sizeof(cols));
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&rows), sizeof(rows));

    for (myCol = cols - 1; myCol >= 0; myCol--) {
      for (myRow = rows - 1; myRow >= 0; myRow--) {
        ColorRGB rgb(img.pixelColor(myCol, myRow));
        cout << "red: "     << (rgb.red()   * 255);
        cout << ", green: " << (rgb.green() * 255);
        cout << ", blue: "  << (rgb.blue()  * 255) << endl;
      }
    }
  }
    catch ( Magick::Exception & error) {
    cerr << "Caught Magick++ exception: " << error.what() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This works great in that it spits out the values for me to see (and make sure it's doing the right thing.)  Note: yes, I am aware that it's starting at the lower right corner and reading down to 0,0.  That's the intention here.

What I need now is figure out how to write those rgb values to the open file.  For each pixel, I get the values from rgb.red() * 255, rgb.green() * 255, and rgb.blue() * 255.  How do I store those as r,g,b (one pixel per line) in the file?

I think I need to do the same char casting on them, but I don't know how to get them concatenated together on a single line.  Each file.write() automatically add an LF at the end.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I guess what I'm not understanding is how to tie them together as one string (separated by commas) and then writing it out.  I can write out the single values just fine (after casting to char*), but I'm unsure how to do all three as a single line in the file.

Comment: Are you writing a text file or a binary file? If it is binary, then why do you need to separate the values with commas?

Comment: p.s. You should declare your variables local to `main()`. Usually global variables are frowned upon, unless you have a specific reason for using them.

Comment: You should change that `endl` to a `\n` or what ever newline you want to go with. `endl` flushes, which is not good in such a large loop. You can flush the stream after the loop using `flush`. just a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that `rgb.red()`, etc. all return `int`. If so, then you can write these values in exactly the same way that you wrote the number of columns and rows:

```
int red = (int)(rgb.red() * 256);
myFile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char*> (&red), sizeof(red));
```

Note that binary files do not have any concept of LF or CR. They only contain binary data which you interpret by `read()` and `write()` calls.

Comment: Actually no, $rgb.color() returns a float (between 0 and 1) which is why it's being multiplied by 255 to get a value between 0 and 255.  But, you mentioned something else in an earlier comment, why separate with commas.  I don't have an answer for that.  I'm used to seeing (ascii) data separated by commas so that was an assumption that I made, that I need to do the same thing here.  I guess I'll write it as is and go from there.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @KirAsh4 You need to decide whether you want to output your data as ASCII text (in which case separating numbers with commas certainly makes sense) or as binary (in which case commas are unnecessary). You also need to decide whether you want to output a color value as a floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0 or as an integer between 0 and 255. Either way, the code I have given above will work for writing binary data. Simply change `int red` to `float red` and, optionally, multiply by 256.

Comment: I'm writing binary, so nix the whole comma thing.  And I need to write the ints between 0 and 255, hence the multiplication in my code above.  255 is the correct value for this, not 256.

Comment: @KirAsh4 Does `rgb.color()` return a value in the closed, open, half-open interval between 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: pixel (0,0) => red: 0.203922, green: 0.196078, blue:  0.207843

Comment: That is, according to Magick++'s documentation, the ratio for that color.  So multiplied by 255 gives me the 0-255 value that I need for my application.

Comment: @KirAsh4 Let me rephrase: can the return value be equal to 1.0 or is it everything up to, but not including 1.0?

Comment: Including.  If the pixel color value is 255, that returns 1.

Comment: @KirAsh4 All right. Good luck with the rest of your project. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, you have been very helpful.  Now I need to figure out why I have so many zeroes in the binary file.  Nothing's easy I suppose.

Comment: @KirAsh4 How are you viewing the binary file?

Comment: Since you are writing binary data with `write()`, you should read it back in with `read()`. `get()` is intended for reading text. Most likely you are seeing a lot of zeroes because you are reading each individual byte rather than the number of bytes that an `int` uses. Since the largest value you write is 255, there will be several 0 bytes for each non-zero byte because an `int` is almost definitely larger than one byte.

Answer (score 1):

Binary files do not have the concept of 'newlines' or lines. They are only for text files to make it readable to us mortal humans. So in that sense, you don't need to worry about newlines. Keep writing the binary color values to the file. The only thing you should be concerned about is who is consuming this file and if the binary format you're using to write to the file is acceptable to that consumer.

Comment: The "consumer" is me.  This is converting an image file to the respective rgb values for every pixel.  That data file then goes on an SD card which an Arduino will then access and pull the data back out and push to a string of LEDs.  This is but step 1 out of a much larger piece.